# Dealing with potentially null datetime value in a SQLParameter

Tags: .net, datetime, sqlparameter

I am trying to do what I thought was a pretty straightforward thing, but am having issue. I have code in a .NET application to insert a new record into a table using SQLCommand.

I am passing in what could either be a datetime value or it could be null. The code below doesn't seem to work though:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SettleDate", 
IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(SettleDate), Nothing, DateTime.Parse(SettleDate)))
```

Where "SettleDate" is a string containing a date that could be null. I would think this code would cover the condition of not attempting to parse a null value, however when it is ran I get the following error which looks to be from the Datetime.Parse method:

```
String reference not set to an instance of a String.
Parameter name: s
```

How could this be? If "SettleDate" is null then it should never reach the parse method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the short circuit opertator of VB.NET together with DbNull.Value

```
If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(SettleDate), DBNull.Value, DateTime.Parse(SettleDate)))
```

[The IF operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx), contrary to IIF function doesn't try to evaluate both sides of the expression if the first one is true. Note also that to pass a null value to an SqlParameter you use [DbNull.Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Ah, that's a very subtle thing I hadn't realized. Thanks.